# Configuring Apache Virtual Hosts Produces Strange Notices

Tags: php, apache

I have what used to be a typical Apache 2.4 installation on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

There is a `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` directory where all configuration files are stored and from where one can enable sites.

Here is one of them titled `localhost.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 127.0.0.1
        ServerAlias sites.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/sites>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have enabled this site. When I navigate to `sites.dev`, I see the contents of that directory being listed since it does not have an `index.php` file. So far, so good.

I then add a `info.php` file to the same directory which looks like this

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

Now, when I navigate to `sites.dev/info.php`, I see a blank page.

Furthermore, when I look at the `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, I see entries like these

```
[Tue Feb 05 22:21:44.281005 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2149] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operat$
[Tue Feb 05 22:21:44.281059 2019] [core:notice] [pid 2149] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Feb 05 22:24:55.006296 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2149] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 05 22:24:56.064108 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2320] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operat$
[Tue Feb 05 22:24:56.064149 2019] [core:notice] [pid 2320] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Could someone tell me what is happening? How can I fix this localhost and the local development environment?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the following sequence of steps:

Install PHP 7 (even though it was already installed)

`apt-get install php`

`apt-get install php-pear php7.0-dev php7.0-zip php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-xml libapache2-mod-php7.0`

`sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif`

`sudo a2enconf php7.0-fpm`

`sudo service apache2 reload`